# How to use query irelationship in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is this:

I have a table "users":

```
id_us | name
-------------
  1   |  bob
  2   |  ken
  3   | jones
```

and I also have a table for pets "pets"

```
id_pet | pet
-------------
  1   |  dog
  2   |  cat
  3   |  fish
```

and a table for storing the relation of user and pets "user_pets"

```
id | id_us  |  pet
-------------------
 1 |  1     |   1 --------> (dog)
 2 |  1     |   2 --------> (cat)
 3 |  2     |   1 --------> (dog)
 4 |  3     |   3 --------> (fish)
 3 |  3     |   2 --------> (cat)
```

I have been trying to create a query that gives me all the users that do not have dogs, the problem of my query is that because the user "Bob" for example has two pets and one of them is not a dog, it is returned in my result for the query even if he is a dog owner.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    usuario.name
FROM 
    usuario
JOIN 
    user_pets ON usuario.id_us = user_pets.id_us
WHERE
    user_pets.pet != 1
GROUP BY 
    usuario.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using `EXISTS`

Inner Query bring all the dogs from the users.

Then if `NOT EXISTS` any result mean Bob doesnt have a dog.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM user_pets up
                   WHERE up.id_pet = 1 
                   AND up.id_us = u.id_us )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    usuario.name
FROM 
    usuario
        LEFT JOIN user_pets
            ON usuario.id_us = user_pets.id_us
            AND  user_pets.pet = 1
WHERE user_pets.id is null
```

OR

```
  SELECT 
        usuario.name
 FROM 
        usuario
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS  (SELECT id_ud FROM  user_pets WHERE  user_pets.pet = 1 ANd USerpets.id_us =  usuario.ID)
```

Or

```
  SELECT 
        usuario.name
 FROM 
        usuario
 WHERE  usuario.ID NOT IN  (SELECT id_ud FROM  user_pets WHERE  user_pets.pet = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   pets p
                   JOIN   users_pets up ON p.id_pet = up.pet
                   WHERE  p.pet = 'dog' AND
                          u.id_us = up.id_us)
```